# why does var behave differently in a with statement depending on whether or not the passed object has a property with the same name?

Tags: javascript

```js
function foo(obj) {
  with(obj) {
    var x = 2;
  }
  console.log(x);
}
let o1 = {};
foo(o1); // 2 (x is visible even outside the with statement because of *var*)

function foo2(obj) {
  with(obj) {
    var x = 2;
  }
  console.log(x);
}
let o2 = {
  x: 1
};
foo2(o2); // undefined (why?)
```

I'm reading along Kyle Simpson's Scope & Closures book from the YDKJS series and I was able to understand all of the quirks of with statements and how `with(obj) { a = 1 }` is functionally different from `obj.a = 1` despite having been intended as a shorthand for it in cases of long object names and having to constantly reference it. This is because the object's properties are treated as lexically defined identifiers in that scope (a vs obj.a), and that in sloppy mode, one side effect of this is that if the object you pass into a with statement doesn't have a property that you are trying to assign to, a global variable of that name will be created. Still, armed with all this knowledge and more, I don't quite understand why the code above behaves the way it does. Why does `foo(o2)` log undefined?

Comment: ["Use of the `with` statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) This is a deprecated feature. Although you may be interested in it purely out of curiosity's sake (or for an academic exercise), I want to be clear that other users should steer clear.

Comment: Have you read the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-WithStatement)?

Comment: Although I'm not prepared to commit to an answer on this because I can't correlate your specific situation to the spec, I suspect that this has something to do with `var` being hoisted to the top of functions. In the first case, because there is no match in the immediate scope, the variable is hoisted and exists at function scope. In the second case, it's treated as a re-declare (as it already exists in the immediate scope), and is therefore not hoisted. An educated guess. I'd be interested to know if there's a better explanation.

Comment: @spender This is the theory I arrived at as well after some thought. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Indeed, if you trace `obj` as well as `x`, you'll see that, even though it looks like you're declaring a new variable `x`, in the second case, you're actually manipulating `obj.x`. I think this more-or-less proves that it's effectively treated as a redeclare, hence the differing behaviour between your 2 cases.

Comment: Just as Phil predicted would happen, a moderator has just swept through to delete a bunch of obsolete comments. @spender, I put a bunch of words into your mouth (edited your original comment). If you have any objections whatsoever to any of my edits, please feel free to delete and repost (and `@` me to gripe, of course). :-) You can flag this comment to self-destruct once you've read it, also.

Comment: @CodyGray No complaints. Perhaps if I'd been a little more verbose at the first comment, it might have shut down the tangential comments a little sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in behaviour can be accounted for by this behaviour, described in (for instance) the following [note in ECMAScript 2022 Language Specification sect `14.3.2.1`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-variable-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> NOTE: If a VariableDeclaration is nested within a with statement and the BindingIdentifier in the VariableDeclaration is the same as a property name of the binding object of the with statement's object Environment Record, then step 5 ***will assign value to the property instead of assigning to the VariableEnvironment binding of the Identifier***.

In the first case:

```
function foo(obj) {
  with(obj) {
    var x = 2;
  }
  console.log(x);
}
let o1 = {};
foo(o1);
```

because `obj` has no `x` property, the `var` statement is hoisted to the top of the function and is therefore visible beyond the scope of the `with` statement.

In the second case:

```
function foo2(obj) {
  with(obj) {
    var x = 2;
  }
  console.log(x);
}
let o2 = {
  x: 1
};
foo2(o2);
```

`x` exists on `obj`, so we satisfy the conditions laid out in the quoted note, and therefore the value is assigned to the property and no hoisted variable is created. Now, there's no `x` outside the scope of the `with` statement.